# Vue lost reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io, vuejs2, reactive-programming

Can't understand why this simple things not reactive.
Looks like I'm missed some Vue's basis.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{connection_status}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            connection_status: 'loading',
        };
    },
    created() {
        Echo.connector.socket.on('connect', function(){
            this.connection_status = 'connected'; 
            console.log(this.connection_status );   
        });
        Echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            this.connection_status = 'disconnected'; 
            console.log(this.connection_status );   
        });
    },  
}
</script>
```

Echo runs throught socket.io and works correct. All events triggers in time.

Console output when connected:

```
connected
```

But on page

```
loading
```

Same thing when disconnected triggers.
In console:

```
disconnected
```

On page

```
loading
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `this` inside the callback function doesn't refer to the Vue instance. You should use an arrow function instead ..

```
created() {
        Echo.connector.socket.on('connect', ()=>{
            this.connection_status = 'connected';
            console.log(this.connection_status );   
        });
        Echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
            this.connection_status = 'disconnected'; 
            console.log(this.connection_status );   
    });
},
```

Or you could assign `this` to a variable and use it in the callback function ..

```
created() {
        const vm = this;
        Echo.connector.socket.on('connect', function(){
            vm.connection_status = 'connected';
            console.log(vm.connection_status );   
        });
        Echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            vm.connection_status = 'disconnected'; 
            console.log(vm.connection_status );   
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript a function is an object. Using `function() {}` defines a new object scope and therefore a new scope for `this`. You are assigning the value to the `connection_status` property on the *function*, not your vue component.

The best practice is to use arrow functions unless you need a new function scope as arrow functions inherit `this` from the scope they are defined in.

```js
Echo.connector.socket.on('connect', () => {
    this.connection_status = 'connected'; 
    console.log(this.connection_status );   
});
Echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    this.connection_status = 'disconnected'; 
    console.log(this.connection_status );   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the mounted() hook instead of the created() one if I understand the doc well : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created